# Angular Ag-Grid tooltip highlight value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm using Angular 10 + Ag-Grid v26.

I'm displaying comma separated values in grid cell as links. I'm also displaying tool tip which same as the value in grid cell but the tooltip is displayed for the entire cell value. Is it possible to display the tooltip for the entire cell value, but when i hover on individual elements, value in the tooltip for that hovered element is may be bolder

```
cellRenderer = (params) => {
  if (params.value !== undefined && params?.value?.length > 0) {
    const crList = params.value.map(crMap => {
      return `<a href="${crMap.url}" target="_blank" rel="noopener">${crMap.crId}</a>`
    }).filter(val => val.trim()).join(', ');

    return crList;
  }
}

//tooltip

tooltipValueGetter = (params: ITooltipParams) => {
   const crToolTip = params?.value?.map(crObj => crObj.crId);
   return crToolTip.toString();
}
```

I couldn't find anything which resolves this issue